# Prove that $x$ and $y$ are divisible by $3$ when $x^2+6u^2=2y^2+3v^2$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

> **a)** Solve  $x^2\equiv 2y^2\pmod{3}$
>
> **b)** Use **part a** to prove that $x$ and $y$ are divisible by $3$ when $x^2+6u^2=2y^2+3v^2$

**My attempt:**
$x^2\equiv 2y^2\pmod{3}\iff $$(y^{-1}x)^2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$ but $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=-1$ since $3 \equiv 3\pmod{8}$. This means that 2 can't be Q.R. but at the same time I showed that $(xy^{-1})^2$ is clearly a square. Does it mean that the inverse doesn't exist?

Comment: The inverse doesn't exists else $2$ is a quadratic residue so $y$ must be divisible with $3$ and then $x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ .This means both $x$ and $y$ are multiples of $3$ .

Comment: For part $b)$ reduce the equation modulo $3$ and then use $a)$ .

Comment: @ComplexPhi Thank you, but I don't see why $y|3$? To have a solution, I know that $\gcd(x^2,3)$ must divide $2y^2$. Now the $\gcd(x^2,3)=1,3$. If it's $3$ then I see why $y|3$ but what if $\gcd(x^2,3)=1$?

Comment: You proved that the inverse $y^{-1}$ modulo $3$ doesn't exist but because $3$ is a prime this happens only when $y \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

Comment: @ComplexPhi Oh, I see. And this automatically deduces part b, after simple rearranging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have $x \equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod 3, $ you get a little extra, since $x^2 \equiv y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9. $ This says something about the other two letters, $ 6 u^2 \equiv 3 v^2  \pmod 9. $ Then  $ 2 u^2 \equiv  v^2  \pmod 3. $ Finally, this part of the conclusion is $u \equiv v \equiv 0 \pmod 3. $

Stated carefully, the result is simply that if 
 $$ x^2 + 6 u^2 \equiv 2 y^2 + 3 v^2  \pmod 9, $$
then
$$ x \equiv u \equiv y \equiv v \equiv 0 \pmod 3. $$ Which means that if
$ x^2 + 6 u^2 \equiv 2 y^2 + 3 v^2  \pmod 9, $ then $$ \gcd(x,u,y,v) \neq 1. $$

Now **assume** we have any integer solution to $$ X^2 + 6 U^2 = 2 Y^2 + 3 V^2   $$
where the only requirement is that **at least one of $X,U,Y,V$ is not equal to $0.$** We may then find
$$ T = \gcd(X,U,Y,V);  $$
in turn, we may define
$$ x = X/T, \; u = U/T, \; y = Y/T, \; v = V/T.  $$
It follows that $  \gcd(x,u,y,v) = 1.  $
It is still true that t least one of $x,u,y,v$ is not equal to $0.$ It is also still true that $x^2 + 6 u^2 = 2 y^2 + 3 v^2.$ However, this means $ x^2 + 6 u^2 \equiv 2 y^2 + 3 v^2  \pmod 9, $ from which we proved that $ \gcd(x,u,y,v) \neq 1. $ This contradicts the assumption that there is any solution in integers $X,U,Y,V$ with at least one of them nonzero.

The final result is that **$x^2 + 6 u^2 = 2 y^2 + 3 v^2$ in integers implies
$x=u=y=v=0.$** Only trivial integer solutions.

Comment: This is a great answer. I think it could also be proven by taking the smallest solution $x+u+v+y>0$, but since $3|x$ and $3|y$ we can write $x=3x_1$ and $y=3y_1$ . But our new results into our equation, rearange and divide by 3, to see that we have $x_1+u+v+y_1>0$ which is smaller, contradicting our assumption